# How to find the last 5 dates? SQL Dev

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Each Sender (Except Amazon) is responsible for sending a document daily. The code below will display all the senders and the dates they have sent the document. I will be able to tell if a sender did NOT send the report every day. My question is... How would I display if I just wanted the last 5 dates for each Sender?

For example.. I want to find the last 5 dates Walmart, Target, and all other senders sent the document.

```
select distinct sender, 
SUBSTR(file_name, 3, 8) date_sent 
from FILE_HEADER hdr, 
 FILE_LINES fl
where hdr.header_id = fl.header_id
and sender not 'Amazon'
order by  
1 , 2 desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick assuming that you have access to `ROW_NUMBER` (it's been available for at the very least 10 years though).

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    sender, SUBSTR(file_name, 3, 8), date_sent,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sender ORDER BY date_sent desc) rn
  FROM FILE_HEADER
) 
WHERE rn <= 5
ORDER BY sender, date_sent desc;
```